# search in part of array list - java

Tags: java, list, search, arraylist

it is possible to do a search for example between the position 5 to 10 in a arrayList?

how?

in this case i need to do a search between position 1-5, 5-10, ... and i want to avoid another lists

EDIT:   i have something like that

```
if (pp.move(i).subList(5, 10).contains(pn50.getText())) {
```

but i have a problem with this code, i needto call a method like:

```
if (pp.move(i).suit().subList(5, 10).contains(pn50.getText())) {
```

but i get an error: The method subList(int, int) is undefined for the type String
thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get a sublist of what you need (which isn't an expensive operation) and then search that entire list. Like so:

```
if (myList.subList(0, 5).contains(objectToFind)) {
   System.out.println("Found object between indexes 0 and 5");
}
```

UPDATE: TO convert your String of suits into a list first, if the string is comma delimited, then you can do it like so:

```
String[] suitArray = pp.move(i).suit().split(",");
List myList = List list = Arrays.asList(suitArray);
```

And then use the first bit of code above to check it. Now, if you are just searching for something in a String, you can probably do it more efficiently by not converting to a List first, but that would be an entirely new question.

Comment: hi Kenny, thanks for your reply. One question please. i need something more. Can you see my post update?

Comment: I don't understand what your updated code is trying to do. suit() is returning a String object, which isn't a List so you definitely can't call subList() on it. What is in the String returned by suit()?

Comment: strings of suit of cards like hearts, clubs, etc

Comment: Ok, I've included code above to convert your String to a List.

Comment: @All,can you post a complete example.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Read [the documentation for java.util.List.subList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29).

Answer (score 0):

is it ok if you grab a sub list ?

```
ArrayList.subList(fromIndex, toIndex);
```

This way you have subset of your items, manipulate them and still not having a "new" list (modifying the sublist will modify the original list)

Answer (score 0):

> but i get an error: The method subList(int, int) is undefined for the type String thanks!!

That has to be because your `suit()` method is declared as returning a `String`.

Comment: for a String, use substring, not subList: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int, int)